# Pivotal Tracker email integration

Tags: pivotaltracker

We are using `PivotalTracker` for task management. A requirement is that when someone sends an email to a company email address like `support@company.com` with the subject line "Bug", it needs to automatically grab the content of the email and create a story in `Pivotal Tracker`.

**Is that possible?**

We have `Pivotal Tracker` integrated with `BugDigger` which requires submitting a bug through `bug digger` interface, but we need a simple email integration.

**Can anyone recommend any free tools/API that can do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that Pivotal tracker allows email integration but only from the subject line of the email. So whatever the subject line contains can be created as a new activity in Pivotal Tracker but does not detect the body of the email.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to documentation on the Pivotal site as to how this works?  I've searched and not found it, and would like more detail on this.